# tex4ht removes spaces in array column when including a package even if the package is not used

Tags: tabularx, tex4ht

In the following cases, `Tex4ht` generates an HTML file with no spaces between the columns of the matrix if some package is included, even if the package is not used.

Removing the package, the space between the columns shows up again.

This only affects tex4ht and not pdflatex.

### tabularx

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx} %commenting this off restores the spaces
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
\[
\left[ \begin {array}{cc}   
                          0      &     1  \\ 
                         -25     &     -4
       \end {array} 
\right] 
\]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### array package

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%    
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array          
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
\[
\left[ \begin {array}{cc}   
                          0      &     1  \\ 
                         -25     &     -4
       \end {array} 
\right] 
\]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following packages also cause the same problem, but this is due to them loading the `array` package internally:  `siunitx`, `ltxtable` and any other package that loads the `array` package will show the above problem.

These problems do not show up with the Latex code is outside the `tabular` environment. As I said in the comment below, this is a small example from large document. I use `tabular` with 2 columns to help me array the layout of the document. Left side is the command and the right side is the output. Both can be latex code as shown above.

Comment: there is no configuration for `tabularx` in `tex4ht`. it seems that this package redefines some spacing parameters and this interfere with `tex4ht`. when using `mathml` output, this problem doesn't show

Comment: @michal.h21 tabularx doesn't change the global array/tabular parameters (locally it messes with local redefinitions of tabular but as it isn't used here that's presumably not relevant)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think this is the issue, Nasser put array inside tabular, when I comment it out, spacing is correct

Comment: @Nasser why do you use tabular here? spacing is correct when you put array outside tabular

Comment: @michal.h21 I know the spacing is correct outside tabular. But this is an example from latex document. I use tabular to arrange commands on left side and output on the right side. So I use a table for this as it is a simple way to do this. It works ok with pdflatex. The output or the input can be latex code so I put it there inside the tabular.

Comment: You know that both `tabularx` and `siunitx` load `array` which is why it is not surprising that you get the same behaviour with them as with `array`?

Comment: @cgnieder Why do you say `You know that both tabularx and siunitx load array` ? How did you know I know? or any user should know this? I am a newbie and just report what I see. I do not look under the cover to see what happens.

Comment: @Nasser you're not that new:-) and the terminal and log file show you all packages loaded every time you run latex:-)

Comment: @Nasser I had a question mark at the end so this was meant as a question... I should probably have written “Do you know [...]?” Any user *can* know this by examining the log file. (Although it sometimes takes a bit experience to know how/where to look.) I didn't want to offend you. Sorry if I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this issue again, and I think you can fix this issue with this version of `array.4ht`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% array.4ht                             2023-11-06-15:09 %
% Copyright (C) 1997-2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
% Copyright 2009-2023 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
  \def\@tabular{\leavevmode
  \hbox \bgroup \:@tabular:
      $\col@sep\tabcolsep \let\d@llarbegin\begingroup
                                    \let\d@llarend\endgroup
  \@tabarray}
\pend:def\@tabular{\let\@array:a\a:tabular \let\@array:b\b:tabular
\let\@array:c\c:tabular \let\@array:d\d:tabular
\let\@array:e\e:tabular \let\@array:f\f:tabular
}
\def\:temp[#1]#2{%
  \def\Clr{#2}\a:VBorder
\HAssign\ar:cnt0
\let\HAlign\empty
%
  \@tempdima \ht \strutbox
  \advance \@tempdima by\extrarowheight
  \setbox \@arstrutbox \hbox{}%
  \begingroup
    \@mkpream{#2}%
    \xdef\@preamble{%
        \everycr{}\tabskip\z@skip\noexpand\MkHalign\noexpand\@sharp
   {\@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\z@skip}%
}%
    \xdef\:temp{%
   \def\noexpand\HAlign{\HAlign}%
   \def\noexpand\ar:cnt{\ar:cnt}}\aftergroup\:temp
%
  \endgroup
  \@arrayleft
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi \fi
  \bgroup
    \def\v:TBL{#1}%
    \let \protect \relax  \lineskip \z@
    \baselineskip \z@ \m@th
    \let\\\@arraycr \let\tabularnewline\\\let\par\@empty
    \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
       \SaveMkHalignConfig %%%%%%%%% \let\sv:ALIGN\HAlign
       \ifx \recall:ar\:UnDef
   \pend:def\@array{\recall:ar}%
   \edef\recall:ar{%
      \noexpand\ifx \noexpand\EndPicture\noexpand\:UnDef \noexpand\else
         \arrayrulewidth\the\arrayrulewidth
         \doublerulesep\the\doublerulesep
         \arraycolsep\the\arraycolsep
         \tabcolsep\the\tabcolsep
      \noexpand\fi }%
\fi
% why did we set these variables to zero? it leads to wrong spacing
% in pictures.
% https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?229
% \arrayrulewidth\z@  \doublerulesep\z@
% \arraycolsep\z@     \tabcolsep\z@
\Configure{MkHalign}
   {\@array:a}%
   {\@array:b\ProperTrTrue}%
   {\a:putHBorder\InitHBorder
    \gHAdvance\cline:cnt by 1
\expandafter\ifx \csname  cw:cline-\cline:cnt\endcsname \relax \else
   \Tag{Cline-\cline:cnt}{}%
\fi
\expandafter\ifx \csname  cw:Cline-\cline:cnt\endcsname \relax \else
   \ht:special{t4ht@[}%
\fi
%
    \ifProperTr{\@array:c}}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:d}%
    \ifomit: \Tag{cline-\cline:cnt}{}\fi
\expandafter\ifx \csname  cw:Cline-\cline:cnt\endcsname \relax \else
   \ht:special{t4ht@]}%
\fi
\global \omit:false
%
    \a:putHBorder\InitHBorder}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:e}\RecallMkHalignConfig\recall:ar}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:f}}
%
       \Configure{MkHalign}%
   {\@array:a}%
   {\@array:b\ProperTrTrue}%
   {\a:putHBorder\InitHBorder \ifProperTr{\@array:c}}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:d}\a:putHBorder\InitHBorder}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:e}%%%%%%%%%%\global \let\HAlign\sv:ALIGN
          \RecallMkHalignConfig\recall:ar}%
   {\ifProperTr{\@array:f}}
%
    \else \let\@sharp##\fi  
    \@preamble}
\HLet\@array\:temp
\HLet\@@array\@array
\let\:tempc\@startpbox
\append:defI\:tempc{\expandafter\everypar
   \expandafter{\the\everypar\everypar{\HtmlPar}\HtmlPar}}
\HLet\@startpbox\:tempc

\def\:tempc{\relax \ifnum\HCol=1 \a:endarray\fi
   \enda:rray}
\HLet\endarray\:tempc
\def\:tempc{\relax \ifnum\HCol=1 \a:endtabular\fi
   \enda:rray $\egroup}
\HLet\endtabular\:tempc
\def\enda:rray{\crcr\ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef \EndMkHalign
   \else \egroup\fi  \egroup \@arrayright \gdef\@preamble{}}
\expandafter \let \csname endtabular*\endcsname\endtabular
\def\:tempc{\@classx
   \@tempcnta \count@
   \prepnext@tok
   \@addtopreamble{\ifcase \@chnum
      \hfil
      \d@llarbegin
      \insert@column
      \d@llarend \hfil \or
      \hskip1sp\d@llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend \hfil \or
      \hfil\hskip1sp\d@llarbegin \insert@column \d@llarend \or
    %
   \vtop \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \@endpbox \or
   \vtop \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \@endpbox \or
   \vbox \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \@endpbox
  \fi}\prepnext@tok}
\HLet\@classz\:tempc
\def\:tempc{\@chclass
 \ifnum \@lastchclass=6 \@ne \@chnum \@ne \else
  \ifnum \@lastchclass=7 5 \else
   \ifnum \@lastchclass=8 \tw@ \else
    \ifnum \@lastchclass=9 \thr@@
   \else \z@
   \ifnum \@lastchclass = 10
      \global \expandafter\let \csname @testpach \ar:cnt\endcsname\@nextchar
%
   \else
   \edef\@nextchar{\expandafter\string\@nextchar}%
   \@chnum
   \if \@nextchar c\z@ \add:ar-\else
    \if \@nextchar l\@ne \add:ar<\else
     \if \@nextchar r\tw@ \add:ar>\else
   \z@ \@chclass
   \if\@nextchar |\@ne \b:VBorder\else
    \if \@nextchar !6 \else
     \if \@nextchar @7 \d:VBorder\else
      \if \@nextchar <8 \else
       \if \@nextchar >9 \else
  10
  \@chnum
  \if \@nextchar m\thr@@ \add:ar m\else
   \if \@nextchar p4 \add:ar p\else
    \if \@nextchar b5 \add:ar b\else
   \z@ \@chclass \z@ \@preamerr \z@ \fi \fi \fi \fi
   \fi \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi}
\HLet\@testpach\:tempc
\def\add:ar#1{\HAdvance\ar:cnt by 1
   \def\ch:class{#1}%
\c:VBorder
   \edef\HAlign{\HAlign 0 \ar:cnt\space #1 }}
\def\HColAlign{\expandafter \ifx\csname
   \expandafter\string\ch:class :T:D\endcsname\relax \else \csname
   \expandafter\string\ch:class :T:D\endcsname\fi}

%
\long\def\:temp#1#2#3{%
   \multispan{#1}\a:multicolumn \begingroup
     \def\@addamp{\if@firstamp \@firstampfalse \else
                \@preamerr 5\fi}%
     \def\Clr{#2}\a:VBorder
\HAssign\ar:cnt0
\let\HAlign\empty
%
\@mkpream{#2}%
\ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
   \def\:temp##1 ##2 ##3 {##3}%
   \xdef\new:span{\new:span\HRow.\HCol\expandafter\:temp\HAlign;}%
\fi
\@addtopreamble\@empty
     \global\let\ch:class\ch:class
     \xdef\:temp{%
   \def\noexpand\HAlign{\HAlign}%
   \def\noexpand\ar:cnt{\ar:cnt}}\aftergroup\:temp
%
   \endgroup
   \def\@sharp{\c:multicolumn#3\d:multicolumn}%
   \@arstrut \@preamble
   \null
   \b:multicolumn
   \ignorespaces}
\HLet\multicolumn\:temp

\def\save@decl{%
  \toks \count@ = \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter {%
     \csname a:array\ifnum\@lastchclass=9
   >\else <\fi \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\expandafter\@nextchar\the\toks
     \expandafter\count@\csname b:array\ifnum\@lastchclass=9
   >\else <\fi\endcsname
}}
\NewConfigure{array>}{2}
\NewConfigure{array<}{2}

\Hinput{array}
\endinput
```

The change is that we don't set array spaces to zero:

```
% why did we set these variables to zero? it leads to wrong spacing
% in pictures.
% https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?229
% \arrayrulewidth\z@  \doublerulesep\z@
% \arraycolsep\z@     \tabcolsep\z@
```

This is the result:

[image]